# CSS div hover to change color by another dragged div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I use Jquery Sortable plugin to implement drag/drop. When dragging a div panel from source and drop to destination box, I want destination drop container to change border and background.

If mouse hovers destination container with following css, destination container div changes border width and background color. It works! But, if mouse drags another div and hovers destination container, it does not work.

How to solve it?

```
  .destination-container {
    outline: 2px dashed #afcedc;
  }

  .destination-container:hover {
    outline: 8px dashed #afcedc;
    background-color: lightgray !important;
  }
```

Comment: Does container div changes class `destination-container` after drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

from the specs jqueryui: [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#visual-feedback)

create a new class like:

```
.destination-container-hover {
  outline: 8px dashed #afcedc;
  background-color: lightgray !important;
}
```

and add the class "destination-container-hover" into the ui-droppable-hover part:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-hover": "destination-container-hover"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

since you didn`t provided more code, I'll give you an example from the jQueryUI website.